# Qprocess and avrdude

Tags: qt, qprocess, avrdude

i'm trying to create a simple QT program that allows me to launch avrdude without using command line operations.

I saw that with Qprocess it's easy to launch any kind of program and I tried succesfully with simple programs like Explorer Word and Others.

The problem is that when i try to open cmd.exe nothing happens, even if i try to pass a batch file containing all the information to launch correctly avrdude.

Here's the code

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->startDetached("cmd.exe",QStringList()<<"C:/avrdude/avr.bat");
```

Comment: Please, edit your post to show how did you pass the batch file to `cmd.exe` in `QProcess`. You may use a batch file which contains a `echo "Hello."` only to form a reproducable sample.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i've edited my code, as you can see i ask to open cmd.exe and then i want to pass the absolute path of my batch file. In my version the absolute path is given by a qstring that save the path obtained from a Qfiledialog

Comment: Looks not bad on the 1st glance. Does `cmd.exe` open and close, or does it stay open. In the former case, you may use '/K' as first argument. I just found this out by typing 'help cmd' in 'cmd.exe'.

Comment: Did you notice that `startDetached()` is `static`? Thus, `QProcess::startDetached(...);` should work. In your case (with an instance of `QProcess`) `start()` is the actual method to use.

Comment: thanks, i wrote it using anything i found here... unfortunately unlike other applications, even if i use startdetached nothing happens... i don't know if it doesn't work or maybe, if it's too fast to see the window before it disappears

Comment: `startDetach()` has a return value which you should check.

Comment: Therefore, I recommended `/K`. It should force `cmd.exe` to stay open after command has been performed.

Comment: I've tried but I've received this message "QProcess: Destroyed while process ("cmd.exe") is still running."

Comment: the only thing that sounds strange is that all programs work fine except for cmd.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136035/discussion-between-scheff-and-deid).

Comment: My very last idea: Try to provide full path of `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a minimal sample application which shows how to start `cmd` with a command using `QProcess::startDetached()` (on button click):

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>

// Qt header:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QPushButton qBtn(QString::fromLatin1("Start cmd"));
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [](bool) {
      bool ret = QProcess::startDetached(
#if 1 // let Windows search for cmd.exe in %PATH%
        QString::fromLatin1("cmd.exe"),
#else // define exact path of cmd.exe
        QString::fromLatin1("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"),
#endif // 1
        QStringList()
        << QString::fromLatin1("/K")
        << QString::fromLatin1("echo Hello"));
      std::cout << "QProcess::startDetached():"
        << (ret ? "OK." : "Failed!") << std::endl;
    });
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qBtn);
  qWin.show();
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

The Qt project file is left as exercise. (Sorry, I used CMake for this.)

Please, note the `#if 1`. If `1` is replaced by `0` the alternative code with full path is used. (During chat session we examined special problems with starting the `cmd.exe`.) On my system, both alternatives did as well.

(My system: Windows 10, VS2013, Qt 5.7)

Answer (score 0):

I too have been working on a Qt program where there are a couple calls to AVRDUDE. This is what worked for me. Here's the code I made for a read of the AVR device through AVRDUDE, followed by a couple of comments.

```
void MainWindow::call_AVRDUDE_read()    //AVR READ
{
    QProcess CommandPrompt;
    QStringList Arguments;
    QString COMPortUsed = (ui->COM_Port_Used->text());                    // get the COM port from the user off UI
    Arguments << "/C avrdude -c arduino -P "+ COMPortUsed +" -b 115200 -p ATmega328P -e  -U eeprom:r:fromEEPROM.bin:r";
    CommandPrompt.start("cmd",Arguments);
    CommandPrompt.waitForFinished();
}
```

Here's something else which may well influence things in your application. In my case, I am reading the AVR's EEPROM. There is another routine that writes the EEPROM, but it is essentially the same as above, but a different script is sent.
In BOTH these cases, the AVRDUDE operation takes a few seconds to perform its task. When you use the `QProcess::startDetached()`, it has the disadvantage that control will return IMMEDIATELY after the AVRDUDE script is called through the QProcess. This can cause problems, if for instance you wanted to (as in my case) read the contents of the EEPROM and try to do so before the read actually completes.

An alternative to `startDetached()` you might consider trying is shown below. This will retain control until the process is finished, which may be pretty important to you. Use these two lines to replace the startDetached() call you are currently using.

```
CommandPrompt.start("cmd",Arguments);
CommandPrompt.waitForFinished();
```

This will wait for the AVRDUDE process to finish before control is returned.

The take away here though is that `QProces::startDetached()` may return prematurely in your application. Just beware of that.